# defining page load function in classes in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make page Load function in a class. in fact I don't want to use code behind, I want to create a class and define all of my functions (like page load and button clicks ,...)  in it .
how I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this for?

Comment: This is exactly what code-behind classes are for.

Comment: I want to implement mv-vm technology, so I should use classes instead of code behinde.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your class inherit from System.Web.UI.Page, and set your aspx file's Page directive to inherit from your class.

But that's basically the same thing as having a code behind page.

Answer (score 0):

Try ASP.NET webforms MVP pattern that allows to do it more object oriented way but you still need to handle page_events. If you need completely stateless, use ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class say pagebase and inherit you codebehind page with this class now the class code is below.

```
public class PageBase :System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public PageBase ()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckSecurity();//any function you want to call before 
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    public virtual void CheckSecurity()
    {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```

Now this class load function will run before the codebehind page page load runs. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I want to know if this helped you?

Comment: can you create an example for me? I don't get it completely... thanks